# Is Apache Hama suitable for building a decision tree?

Tags: java, hadoop, decision-tree, hama

I currently have implemented in Hadoop, Google's framework for building decision trees (also known as PLANET). It starts with a single vertex and with map reduce jobs you add more and more until the tree is fully build. One major problem though is the fact that a lot of map/reduce jobs run one after another, so the cost of starting new jobs all the time is very high.

I have seen many times that Apache Hama is suitable for iterative algorithms like graphs. Can someone build a new graph with Hama or you just have as input a graph and make some computations on it? Will it be easy to transfer my project to Hama?? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm from the Hama team, I would help you build something like that as it could be a good suit for our machine learning module. Would you mind coming over to the hama-dev mailing list and ask your question again? (http://hama.apache.org/mail-lists.html). The graph module is not so suitable for that in my opinion.

Comment: But to make it less exciting for you, yes Hama can do this very efficient. I had this on my roadmap, but I wasn't able to get deeper into it.

Comment: I have seen your post many times Thomas and in fact i learnt Hama from you :P. I send to the list as you said

Answer (score 2):

Hama is indeed able to construct a Decision Tree using the algorithm described in the PLANET paper, in a much more efficient way than MapReduce.

Hama does not need a graph as input, you can have a look at the Hama ML (machine learning) module that usually deals with raw feature vectors as input directly from HDFS.

For Hama I have created a [new issue in the Apache Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HAMA-653) to track progress on this algorithm.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @JBCP are you the answer police? I can't upvote my own answer, you should update your bot :p

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @showdev of course this answers the question, we added a ticket for that matter and resolve his question with that. If you look closely, I commented on the question already. Given that this is 2 years old I have no clue why this is coming up now.

Comment: In my opinion, an unresolved support ticket does not constitute an answer. It would be better as a comment.

Comment: @showdev then vote for a deletion of this answer, I don't see why anyone would care. Given my answer attracted two upvotes and hundreds of pageviews.

Comment: Your answer came up as previously written during routine moderation, I did vote for deletion. I see you have quite a high reputation here, so I assume you know how that works. Prior to your edits, it did not answer the question in a format suitable for StackOverflow. I don't know why I was shown a 2 year old answer, but thats what I got. The comment added to your answer was auto generated based on the selection I made (based on the original content of the message. I see you've updated the comment and it looks like the answer is much more appropriate now. @showdev - thank you.